# Call Rust with arguments

Tags: c, rust, arguments, ffi

I've been trying to call a Rust function from C with multiple string arguments, but for some reason the only argument that being sent is the first. This is what I've tried:

input.c

```
extern void print_str(char str1, char str2);

void c_function() {
    scanf("%s %s", str1, str2);
    print_str(str1, str2);
}
```

lib.rs:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn print_str(str1: &str, str2: &str) {
    unsafe {
       libc::printf(str1.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_char);
       libc::printf(str2.as_ptr() as *const libc::c_char);
    }
}
```

Comment: The Rust code [issues a warning](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81c06e16a93319ff2490e80f60094162): *"`extern` fn uses type `str`, which is not FFI-safe"* with a recommendation: *"consider using `*const u8` and a length instead, string slices have no C equivalent"*

Comment: And, in C `char` is different from `const char *`. You intend to provide strings but your C declaration expects two _single_ characters.

Answer (score 3):

First, the code you provide is straight up broken, the C snippet makes absolutely no sense.

Second, your types are *completely* mismatched.

`&str` is a Rust type, C has no equivalent builtin type, and it most certainly is not equivalent to a C string, its low-level payload (the underlying buffer) is not even compatible with C strings because *Rust strings are not nul-terminated*. The compiler literally tells you that:

```
warning: `extern` fn uses type `str`, which is not FFI-safe
 --> src/lib.rs:2:35
  |
2 | pub extern "C" fn print_str(str1: &str, str2: &str) {
  |                                   ^^^^ not FFI-safe
  |
  = note: `#[warn(improper_ctypes_definitions)]` on by default
  = help: consider using `*const u8` and a length instead
  = note: string slices have no C equivalent
```

Furthermore, from the C side you're sending a `char` not even a C string.

So what you're doing here is sending two characters, telling Rust that they're really two rust strings, and then misusing *that* as two C strings, your code has as many UBs as it has lines.

The Rust function should be taking `*mut c_char`, and the C `extern` should be defined as taking two `char*`.

Comment: I got it to work even with the wrong types.

Comment: No you did not "get it to work". You got it to compile because *the types can't be checked in an FFI situation*, the compiler can only trust that you know what you're doing.

Comment: It runs and to me that's all that really matters.

Comment: You do you, just please don't come back asking questions when things randomly don't work: you're yolo-ing unsafe and your code is UB central despite advice to the contrary.

Answer (score -1):

C code:

```c
extern void print_str(char *str1, char *str2);

void c_function() {
   char str1[10];
   char str2[10];
   scanf("%s "%s", str1, str2);
   print_str(str1, str2);
}
```

Rust code:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn print_str(str1: &str, str2: &str) {
    unsafe {
        libc::printf(str1.as_ptr() as *const c_char);
        libc::printf(str2.as_ptr() as *const c_char);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct. Your signature is lying about what it expects.